# keep track of how many friends clicked "Like"

Tags: facebook

I want to develop an application (Facebook) that is able to invite friends to a fan page and keep track of how many friends (among those invited), clicked "Like" and complete the registration within the application.

Comment: I can't speak fully on this subject, but I believe that would be partly up to you to monitor the actual "Like" button's activity on your site/blog. In javascript, you could put assign an [Observer event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005300/example-of-javascript-observer-pattern) to monitor when the user clicks the button and [`DO STUFF HERE`].

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Facebook Dev page here is information pertaining to your request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ . Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Good answer. I read it, and found [this link at the bottom](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). This is exactly what the OP wanted. +1.

Comment: Thank you for the +1. I'm definitely trying to become more knowledgeable about the Facebook SDK and even though I'm definitely new to it I think it is really cool to read!

Comment: I'm glad you think it's cool. Personally, I find it rather overpowered and pervasive. But eh, whatever. `;)`

Comment: I do not mean like the button of my application as a plugin ... But the button like a fan page.

Comment: I just saw that you created two other related posts so I have no sympathy anymore and dont feel like helping.